# Slow SQL query - sub query

Tags: postgresql

I have a view which is called `vProductScoreDetail` which calculates the individual score of three metrics that have been applied to each product. It contains a lot of `case` and other statements to calculate each score but it is fast enough, returning queries in under a second.

I now want to total those three detail scores into an "overall" score, and I am now getting performance issues (15sec+ to return overall scores). I have used a nested view to do this. My `vProductScoreOverall` view looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public."vProductScoreOverall"
 AS
 SELECT vpsd."userId",
    vpsd.type,
    vpsd."productId",
    sum(vpsd."scoreWeighted")::integer AS "scoreWeighted",
    sum(vpsd."excludeCount")::integer AS "excludeCount",
        CASE
            WHEN count(DISTINCT vpsd."refScoreMetricCode") >= 3 THEN true
            ELSE false
        END AS "isDataComplete"
   FROM "vProductScoreDetail" vpsd
  WHERE 1 = 1
  GROUP BY vpsd."userId", vpsd.type, vpsd."productId";
```

I tried putting a nested subquery in instead of nesting views so the planner has visibility but the query time was the same. I cannot materialise any views either as the metrics can be dynamic to each user, so they need to be generated dynamically. Any tips on what I could do to optimise this final overall sum of the scores from the detailed scores?

Here's an explain analyse output to assist where I can optimise things... `explain analyze select * from "vProductScoreOverall" vpsd limit 1000`

```
QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=965124.03..968461.23 rows=1000 width=77) (actual time=27617.730..27642.267 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=965124.03..1657936.27 rows=208227 width=77) (actual time=26130.662..26152.508 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Group Key: up."userId", (CASE WHEN (up."userId" = 'default'::text) THEN 'default'::text ELSE 'personal'::text END), p.id
        ->  Sort  (cost=965124.03..971745.65 rows=2648645 width=164) (actual time=26130.577..26135.090 rows=1233 loops=1)
              Sort Key: up."userId", (CASE WHEN (up."userId" = 'default'::text) THEN 'default'::text ELSE 'personal'::text END), p.id
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 278520kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34865.56..248009.68 rows=2648645 width=164) (actual time=1215.785..19755.806 rows=882456 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on "userPref" up  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.032..0.052 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Filter: ("refUserPrefTypeCode" = 'scoring_metric'::text)
                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=34865.56..214900.58 rows=2648645 width=68) (actual time=1063.990..5626.202 rows=294152 loops=3)
                          Hash Cond: (vpsm."productId" = p.id)
                          ->  Subquery Scan on vpsm  (cost=24780.45..134970.64 rows=2648645 width=68) (actual time=148.073..3238.083 rows=281032 loops=3)
                                ->  Append  (cost=24780.45..108484.19 rows=2648645 width=260) (actual time=148.069..2468.913 rows=281032 loops=3)
                                      CTE parents
                                        ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..6278.35 rows=37699 width=170) (actual time=0.028..17.852 rows=714 loops=1)
                                              ->  Seq Scan on company  (cost=0.00..72.15 rows=589 width=141) (actual time=0.019..3.643 rows=589 loops=1)
                                                    Filter: ("parentCompanyId" IS NULL)
                                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 126
                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=81.09..545.22 rows=3711 width=170) (actual time=3.015..5.612 rows=62 loops=2)
                                                    Hash Cond: (p_2.id = c."parentCompanyId")
                                                    ->  WorkTable Scan on parents p_2  (cost=0.00..117.80 rows=5890 width=40) (actual time=0.003..0.543 rows=357 loops=2)
                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=72.15..72.15 rows=715 width=141) (actual time=5.564..5.566 rows=126 loops=1)
                                                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB
                                                          ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..72.15 rows=715 width=141) (actual time=0.019..1.397 rows=715 loops=1)
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=18502.10..59678.16 rows=2449682 width=265) (actual time=148.065..1371.192 rows=82069 loops=3)
                                            Hash Cond: (prod."brandId" = b.id)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on product prod  (cost=0.00..6668.27 rows=208227 width=8) (actual time=0.017..413.030 rows=207027 loops=3)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=11597.11..11597.11 rows=173279 width=193) (actual time=135.930..135.930 rows=2027 loops=3)
                                                  Buckets: 32768  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 276kB
                                                  ->  Merge Join  (cost=8830.03..11597.11 rows=173279 width=193) (actual time=46.101..71.929 rows=2027 loops=3)
                                                        Merge Cond: (b."companyId" = p_1.id)
                                                        ->  Sort  (cost=1602.01..1638.83 rows=14729 width=8) (actual time=37.011..41.318 rows=2028 loops=3)
                                                              Sort Key: b."companyId"
                                                              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1075kB
                                                              ->  Seq Scan on brand b  (cost=0.00..582.29 rows=14729 width=8) (actual time=0.017..56.425 rows=14729 loops=1)
                                                        ->  Materialize  (cost=7228.03..7416.52 rows=37699 width=193) (actual time=9.072..14.685 rows=2298 loops=3)
                                                              ->  Sort  (cost=7228.03..7322.27 rows=37699 width=193) (actual time=27.203..28.287 rows=712 loops=1)
                                                                    Sort Key: p_1.id
                                                                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 80kB
                                                                    ->  CTE Scan on parents p_1  (cost=0.00..753.98 rows=37699 width=193) (actual time=0.037..25.772 rows=714 loops=1)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on "productScoreMetric"  (cost=0.00..4787.63 rows=198963 width=196) (actual time=0.023..375.273 rows=198963 loops=3)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=6668.27..6668.27 rows=208227 width=4) (actual time=913.104..913.104 rows=207027 loops=3)
                                Buckets: 131072  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 2840kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on product p  (cost=0.00..6668.27 rows=208227 width=4) (actual time=0.017..444.154 rows=207027 loops=3)
Planning Time: 1.257 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 55
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 10.312 ms, Inlining 20.160 ms, Optimization 903.558 ms, Emission 562.204 ms, Total 1496.233 ms
Execution Time: 33422.479 ms
```

EDIT: Thank you for the comments, I will try them all starting with increasing the memory and see if that makes a difference. For the complete picture, here's the `vProductScoreDetail` view/query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public."vProductScoreDetail"
AS SELECT up."userId",
        CASE
            WHEN up."userId" = 'default'::text THEN 'default'::text
            ELSE 'personal'::text
        END AS type,
    up."refUserPrefTypeCode",
    p.id AS "productId",
    up.data,
    vpsm."refScoreMetricCode",
    vpsm.country,
    vpsm.percentage,
    vpsm."companyId",
    vpsm."desc",
    vpsm."statusModeration",
        CASE
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'made'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'made'::text) ->> 'target'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN (100::numeric * (((up.data -> 'made'::text) ->> 'weight'::text)::numeric))::integer
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'made'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 0
                ELSE 0
            END
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'own'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'own'::text) ->> 'target'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN (100::numeric * (((up.data -> 'own'::text) ->> 'weight'::text)::numeric))::integer
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'own'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 0
                ELSE 0
            END
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'ing'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'ing'::text) ->> 'target'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN (vpsm.percentage::numeric * (((up.data -> 'ing'::text) ->> 'weight'::text)::numeric))::integer
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'ing'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 0
                ELSE 0
            END
            ELSE NULL::integer
        END AS "scoreWeighted",
        CASE
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'made'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'made'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'own'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'own'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'ing'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'ing'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
            ELSE NULL::integer
        END AS "excludeCount",
        CASE
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'made'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'made'::text) ->> 'target'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 'pass'::text
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'made'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 'fail'::text
                ELSE 'neutral'::text
            END
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'own'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'own'::text) ->> 'target'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 'pass'::text
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'own'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 'fail'::text
                ELSE 'neutral'::text
            END
            WHEN vpsm."refScoreMetricCode" = 'ing'::text THEN
            CASE
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'ing'::text) ->> 'target'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 'pass'::text
                WHEN (((up.data -> 'ing'::text) ->> 'exclude'::text)::jsonb) @> concat('["', vpsm.country, '"]')::jsonb THEN 'fail'::text
                ELSE 'neutral'::text
            END
            ELSE NULL::text
        END AS status
   FROM "userPref" up
     CROSS JOIN product p
     LEFT JOIN "vProductScoreMetric" vpsm ON p.id = vpsm."productId"
  WHERE 1 = 1 AND up."refUserPrefTypeCode" = 'scoring_metric'::text;
```

and the `explain analyze select * from "vProductScoreDetail" vpsd limit 1000`

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Limit  (cost=34865.56..35331.66 rows=1000 width=303) (actual time=1341.507..1520.844 rows=1000 loops=1)                                                                   |
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34865.56..1269394.33 rows=2648645 width=303) (actual time=1341.501..1518.261 rows=1000 loops=1)                                                  |
        ->  Seq Scan on "userPref" up  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=96) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)                                                        |
              Filter: ("refUserPrefTypeCode" = 'scoring_metric'::text)                                                                                                    |
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=34865.56..256286.58 rows=2648645 width=135) (actual time=1341.298..1505.238 rows=1000 loops=1)                                         |
              Hash Cond: (vpsm."productId" = p.id)                                                                                                                        |
              ->  Subquery Scan on vpsm  (cost=24780.45..134970.64 rows=2648645 width=135) (actual time=163.108..316.151 rows=3922 loops=1)                               |
                    ->  Append  (cost=24780.45..108484.19 rows=2648645 width=260) (actual time=163.103..305.665 rows=3922 loops=1)                                        |
                          CTE parents                                                                                                                                     |
                            ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..6278.35 rows=37699 width=170) (actual time=0.051..10.874 rows=714 loops=1)                                   |
                                  ->  Seq Scan on company  (cost=0.00..72.15 rows=589 width=141) (actual time=0.024..1.758 rows=589 loops=1)                              |
                                        Filter: ("parentCompanyId" IS NULL)                                                                                               |
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 126                                                                                                       |
                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=81.09..545.22 rows=3711 width=170) (actual time=1.720..2.892 rows=62 loops=2)                                      |
                                        Hash Cond: (p_2.id = c."parentCompanyId")                                                                                         |
                                        ->  WorkTable Scan on parents p_2  (cost=0.00..117.80 rows=5890 width=40) (actual time=0.003..0.581 rows=357 loops=2)             |
                                        ->  Hash  (cost=72.15..72.15 rows=715 width=141) (actual time=2.892..2.893 rows=126 loops=1)                                      |
                                              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 19kB                                                                               |
                                              ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..72.15 rows=715 width=141) (actual time=0.011..1.658 rows=715 loops=1)                |
                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=18502.10..59678.16 rows=2449682 width=265) (actual time=163.099..295.986 rows=3922 loops=1)                                |
                                Hash Cond: (prod."brandId" = b.id)                                                                                                        |
                                ->  Seq Scan on product prod  (cost=0.00..6668.27 rows=208227 width=8) (actual time=0.144..67.242 rows=30065 loops=1)                     |
                                ->  Hash  (cost=11597.11..11597.11 rows=173279 width=193) (actual time=149.571..149.572 rows=2027 loops=1)                                |
                                      Buckets: 32768  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 276kB                                                                                    |
                                      ->  Merge Join  (cost=8830.03..11597.11 rows=173279 width=193) (actual time=112.062..132.766 rows=2027 loops=1)                     |
                                            Merge Cond: (b."companyId" = p_1.id)                                                                                          |
                                            ->  Sort  (cost=1602.01..1638.83 rows=14729 width=8) (actual time=95.741..98.830 rows=2028 loops=1)                           |
                                                  Sort Key: b."companyId"                                                                                                 |
                                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1075kB                                                                                  |
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on brand b  (cost=0.00..582.29 rows=14729 width=8) (actual time=0.025..49.058 rows=14729 loops=1)          |
                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=7228.03..7416.52 rows=37699 width=193) (actual time=16.308..23.359 rows=2298 loops=1)                  |
                                                  ->  Sort  (cost=7228.03..7322.27 rows=37699 width=193) (actual time=16.300..17.372 rows=712 loops=1)                    |
                                                        Sort Key: p_1.id                                                                                                  |
                                                        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 80kB                                                                              |
                                                        ->  CTE Scan on parents p_1  (cost=0.00..753.98 rows=37699 width=193) (actual time=0.058..14.438 rows=714 loops=1)|
                          ->  Seq Scan on "productScoreMetric"  (cost=0.00..4787.63 rows=198963 width=196) (never executed)                                               |
              ->  Hash  (cost=6668.27..6668.27 rows=208227 width=4) (actual time=1174.682..1174.683 rows=207027 loops=1)                                                  |
                    Buckets: 131072  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 2840kB                                                                                                     |
                    ->  Seq Scan on product p  (cost=0.00..6668.27 rows=208227 width=4) (actual time=0.471..446.470 rows=207027 loops=1)                                  |
Planning Time: 32.678 ms                                                                                                                                                  |
Execution Time: 1706.232 ms                                                                                                                                               |
```

EDIT2: I have

- changed the `left join` to `join` in `vProductScoreDetail` and that has made a significant to speed up to that view, it made `vProductScoreOverall` view faster but not by much
- increased `work_mem` to 400MB - I didn't see any speed up and looking at the `explain analyze` it's still swapping to disk for the sort which is taking 20s. I have verified work_mem is 400MB via `select name, setting, unit, source from pg_settings where name = 'work_mem';`. Any other clues for forcing the sort to happen in memory?

Comment: `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 278520kB` is what's killing you.  Sorting 278MB of data on disk instead of in memory.  Try increasing your `work_mem` an additional 300MB or so?

Comment: I actually don't see any obvious place where an index could help here, because your query has no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, nor does it use `MAX` or `MIN`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: It will not have any effect on performance, but your CASE expression can be simplified to: `count(DISTINCT vpsd."refScoreMetricCode") >= 3 as "isDataComplete"`

Comment: @richyen: the disk sort only adds 5 seconds to the previous 20 seconds to group the data

Comment: You could try to disable jit: `set jit=off` before running it, but it doesn't seem to make a big difference

Comment: PosgtreSQL 12 can **inline CTEs** (under certain conditions), so new external expressions can be computed side by side. See https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-12-released-1976/

Comment: The fundamental problem here is probably many layers of views that obscure what is going on and make the query impossible to debug. Try rewriting it from scratch, avoiding more than one level of views. At any rate, we cannot help without knowing the views, which involve complicated tools like recursive CTEs. Perhaps a materialized view or two could save you without rewriting everything.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe (apologies I can only put one 'at' reference in these comments), Tim, richen, a_horse_with_no_name, The impaler - I have updated the original comment with the sub query - would appreciate any input you have now with the full information.